# Объявление свойства с инициализацией модели php

Tags: php

Правильно ли объявлять свойство как инициализацию модели в php? Есть ли принятые в сообществе стандарты на эту тему?
Пример кода:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use App\Models\UsersModel;

class Login extends BaseController
{
   private $usersModel;

   function __construct()
   {
      $this->usersModel = new UsersModel();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не запрещено.

---

Для простых типов данных обычно указывают при объявлении свойств:

```
private $count = 3;
```

---

Для сложных объектов со сложной инициализацией обычно используют паттерн [builder](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/builder).

---

Так же хорошей практикой является [внедрение зависимостей](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Structural/DependencyInjection/README.html):

```
class Login extends BaseController
{
    private $usersModel;

    public function __construct(UserModel $model)
    {
        $this->usersModel = $model;
    }
}
```